# Is there is a data race when you send a message to channel and close it?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I encountered a data race , like this

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
11652 Read by goroutine 14:
11653   runtime.chansend()
11654       /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/chan.c:155 +0x0
            ...
11657
11658 Previous write by goroutine 13:
11659   runtime.closechan()
11660       /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/chan.c:1232 +0x0
            ...
```

The channel has a lock, why is there a data race?

Comment: I see two different routines, one is sending and one is closing. It most obviously is data race. What do you mean by saying that channel has a lock? Would you show the relevant code?

Comment: Different goroutine using the same channel shouldn't has a data race.  channel has lock in its implements.

Comment: you need to provide more code.

Comment: Please provide the code that causes the data race. It's hard to answer questions about your code without your code.

Answer (score 1):

A channel is being written to after it has been closed.  Even if there were just a single goroutine, you'd see a panic.

```
package main

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})
    close(c)
    c <- struct{}{}  // should panic!
}
```

What you've got is a variety of this, but with one goroutine closing, and the other goroutine is trying to write afterwards.  The race detector is properly reporting this as a data race.

Why is the channel being closed in your program?

Comment: This data race can happen when the single goroutine scenario does not cause a panic.